# URL With Jquery Mobile

Tags: url, jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-mobile

```
 <!-- this is my conexion.html -->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>

 </head>


<body>


<!-- call ajax page -->
<div data-role="page" id="callAjaxPage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Connexion</h1>
        <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"  class="ui-btn-right jqm-home">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
                <h3>Sign in</h3>
        <form id="callAjaxForm" method="post" action="conexion.php">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  />

                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  />
                <h3 id="notification"></h3>
                <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Go</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
            <h3>Create an account </h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Pied de page</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
   </html>

  <!--- this is my conexion.php -->

    <?php

include('config.php');// connexion to mysql

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$request=mysql_query("select * from utilisateur where nom='$email' and password='$password'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($request);
if ($count==0){
    echo "User not found";
}
else echo "Utilisateur founded";

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery mobile will [enhance forms with ajax by default](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-sample.html) (you don't have to write the ajax for it manually).

Try setting the action of your form to the handler php file, and let jQuery mobile do the rest. e.g:

```
<form method="post" action="conexion.php">
    ...
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Let us know how you go!

**EDIT**:
Based on discussion in the comments, you will also need to add some output to your **conexion.php** file.

I'd also recommend escaping any user input before adding it to an SQL query (for security's sake). e.g:

```
<?php
    // conexion.php

    include('config.php');// connexion to mysql

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Escape user input (unless magic quotes has done it already)
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
    }

    $request=mysql_query(sprintf(
        "select * from utilisateur where nom='%s' and password='%s'",
        $email,
        $password
    ));
    $count = mysql_num_rows($request);


?>
<div data-role="page">
    <?php
        if ($count==0){
            echo "<p>Username or password invalid.</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>You're in! <a href=\"secure-home.php\">Continue to the app</a>.</p>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: so i can delete this ? $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "conexion.php",
                cache: false,
                data: formData,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            });

Comment: Should be able to, yes. You shouldn't need that entire script block. How'd it go?

Comment: when I do that, there is an error "Undefined", because "conexion.php" does not receive the email and password values

Comment: Which version of jQuery mobile are you using? Is the Undefined error in JS or PHP?

Comment: Im using Beta 2, i think that the problem is the URL that changes each time, because when i put data-ajax="false" it works

Comment: Which URL changes each time? Are you using the GET method on the form? Try using POST instead. e.g <form method="post" ...

Comment: I  have editing the source code, thanks for take a look with me

Comment: I'll just setup a dev envrionment with JQM and take a look. Gimme 10.

Comment: Your response needs to contain a <div data-role="page">...</div> otherwise jQuery mobile will print 'undefined'. Let me know if you have any other issues.

Comment: thank u irama, now i would , once the user logged redirects him to home page from conexion.php to "index.html"

Comment: No worries, happy to help. As an easy solution, I have added a 'continue to the app' link to the code sample in my answer above. As for redirects, unfortunately jQuery mobile currently doesn't follow server-side redirects after processing an ajax form submission, but you could probably achieve it using JavaScript. But I think that would be better followed up in another question. This question has been answered I think?

Comment: You might also want to consider adding your original question back to your post at the top (along with your code samples), otherwise this question is likely to be deleted (then no one else can benefit from it).